# Can poison action card destroy Warbot?

Tags: smash-up

In the Smash Up game, Ninjas have a poison action card. Will it have any effect on Warbot, who is a minion which cannot be destroyed?

> Poison - Play on a minion. Destroy any number of actions on it. Ongoing: This minion has -4 power. (Minions have minimum power of 0.)
>
> Warbot - power 4 - Ongoing: This minion cannot be destroyed.

Answer (score 7):

No, it can't destroy Warbot, but that's because it can't destroy minions in general. It can only destroy *actions* attached to a minion, and Warbot doesn't prevent that.

Poison affects Warbot as any other minion because Warbot's ability has no effect on Poison's ability.

- Poison doesn't destroy minions.
- Warbot's ability doesn't prevent actions from being played.
- Warbot's ability doesn't prevent actions attached to the Warbot from being destroyed.
- Warbot's ability doesn't prevent the Warbot's power from being reduced.

Answer (score 4):

**The Poison card does not destroy Warbot.**

The Poison card does not destroy **any** minion directly. Reducing a minions power to 0 does not destroy it.  It hangs around until an effect destroys it or the base that it is on scores.

Answer (score 0):

> In the Smash Up game, Ninjas have a poison action card. Will it have any effect on Warbot, who is a minion which cannot be destroyed?

Will it have any effect. Yes. The effect will be to reduce the power to 0. However poison doesn't destoy the minion merely reduces it's power. To the Warbot will be a minon of 0 power. While most of the time this is an academic point there are cards that are affected by minion prescence. For instance

> Count how many minions you have on a base. Destroy a minion with that power less than or equal to that number.

In this instance, the Warbot though it does not give any power, would still count as a minion. Plus the poison action can be removed restoring the Warbot to full power or the Warbot can have other actions placed on it that increase it's power to again.